# Manipulação de HTML com PHP/JS

Tags: php, javascript, dom

Como obter o conteúdo de uma página com **JavaScript**?

Com o conteúdo obtido através de JavaScript (ou PHP), como manipulá-lo nas duas linguagens, afim de ler os valores, assim como fazemos em JavaScript quando estamos manipulando os elementos DOM.

**O que quero fazer?**

Capturar valores de uma sequência de 50 URLS(logo 50 páginas), que seguem o mesmo padrão de formatação, como o site que desejo realizar tal façanha não disponibiliza uma API para me devolver os dados em um formato de fácil manipulação(como devolvendo dados em XML ou JSON), penso que a única maneira seria obter os dados com cURL ou file_get_contents, e manipulando todo este texto em HTML, a **questão principal é como manipular um texto formatado em HTML com PHP**.

Eu citei como manipular com Javascript um texto(que poderia ter sido obtido com iframe por exemplo) apenas afim de aproveitar o âmbito da pergunta e sanar essa outra dúvida.

Comment: Não entendo o motivo de manipular o conteúdo HTML com PHP, visto que com JS funciona bonitinho, e sem ser muito custoso ao servidor, PHP tem a sua maior utilidade back-end, gravação de dados, recuperação dos mesmos e etc. A não ser que seja uma busca dinâmica em que um refresh na pagina não seja muito custoso ao servidor. Tem como dar exemplos de utilização?

Comment: Podes explicar melhor a pergunta?

Comment: Manipular o `DOM` com JS é uma coisa, e usar o XML é outra também, mas qual é a necessidade de manipular usando ambos ? É realmente necessário ?

Comment: Gostaria de manipular um HTML para simplesmente obter um valor que está na página, infelizmente não têm API no site onde este valor seria me devolvido em formato JSON ou XML, então faço no estilo que dá, que seria obter o HTML da página e manipula-lo a afim de obter o valor que estou procurando. Eu poderia dizer que tenho uma relação de 50 URLS, e essas URLS levam a produtos diferentes, apenas quero capturar o valor dos produtos(que ficam visíveis na página e obedecem a uma padrão de formatação) e gravar no banco de dados as URLS e seus respectivos valores.

Comment: Não é nada que envolve o cliente, apenas para não fazer manualmente gostaria que esse processo fosse automático, ir até o produto da URL, capturar o valor, e gravar no banco de dados, por isso de estar privilegiando PHP.

Answer (score 2):

Um exemplos simples e funcional de como obter o html de uma página, bem como recuperar determinado valor de dentro deste html pode ser encontrado aqui: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net

Mas faço minha as palavras do nosso camarada Marcelo.

Só realize este tipo de ação no back-end se for realmente necessário, ou seja, em ultimo recurso.